# equivalente de async de # en java

Tags: java, hilos, audio, async

Estoy realizando un programa en java que convierte una lista de audios de wav a mp3. Todo va bien hasta que quero mostrar el proceso de conversion en una lista.

En vez de hacerlo progresivamente me muestra todos los progresos de una sola vez cuando ya se han realizado todas las conversiobes.

Este mismo programa ya lo realize en c# y solucione el mismo problema con async / await

He estado buscando cual podría ser el equivalente de async / await en java pero no he encontrado nada,
lo he intentado con un pool de conexiones pero no funciona.

Pool de conexiones:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PJEditCreate.songs.size(); i = 0) {
                c++;
                cancion = PJEditCreate.songs.get(i);
                PJEditCreate.songs.remove(i);
                
                render(Constants.PROJECT+"/img/c.png", false);
                
                try {
                    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                    Future<Boolean> con = es.submit(new HLConvers(cancion));
                    
                    while (!con.isDone()) {}
                    
                    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) this.files.table.getModel();
                    modelo.removeRow(i);
                    
                    render(Constants.PROJECT+"/img/f.png", true); 
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    File f = new File(cancion.getRutaOut());
                    if(f.exists()) {
                        f.delete();
                    }
                    render(Constants.PROJECT+"/img/e.png", true);
                    ex.getStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Thread:

```
public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        if(PJEditCreate.tp.getFormat().equals("mp3")) {
            Convers.convertMp3(new File(cancion.getRuta()), new File(cancion.getRutaOut()));
        }else {
            Convers.convertWav(new File(cancion.getRuta()), new File(cancion.getRutaOut()));
        }
        
        AudioFile audiofile = AudioFileIO.read(new File(cancion.getRutaOut()));
        Tag tag = audiofile.getTag();
        Artwork a = new Artwork();
        a.setBinaryData(Functions.getRenderImg(cancion.getImg()));
        tag.addField(a);
        tag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM, cancion.getDatos().get("ALBUM"));
        tag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST, cancion.getDatos().get("ARTIST"));
        tag.setField(FieldKey.GENRE, cancion.getDatos().get("GENRE"));
        tag.setField(FieldKey.TITLE, cancion.getDatos().get("TITLE"));
        tag.setField(FieldKey.TRACK, cancion.getDatos().get("TRACK"));
        tag.setField(FieldKey.COMMENT, cancion.getDatos().get("COMMENT"));
        tag.setField(FieldKey.YEAR, cancion.getDatos().get("YEAR"));
        tag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM_ARTIST, cancion.getDatos().get("ALBUM_ARTIST"));
        AudioFileIO.write(audiofile);
        return null;
    }
```

Ahi alguna clase equivalente al async / await de c#

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Mi problema era hacer todo el proceso dentro de un for y en el mismo hilo asi que he tenido que buscar algo que supliera al ciclo for.

Un Timer es una especie de hilo que se va ejecutando cada cierto tiempo con lo que ha pododo hacerme las veces de  for.

Código:

```
timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(ser == null) {
                        cancion = PJEditCreate.songs.get(c);
                        PJEditCreate.songs.remove(c);
                        tam++;
                        render(Constants.pro.get(pro), false);
                        es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                        ser = es.submit(new HLConvers(cancion));
                    }
                    else {
                        if(ser.isDone()) {
                            boolean isOk;
                            try {
                                isOk = ser.get();
                            } catch (Exception e1) {
                                isOk = false;
                            }
                            
                            if(!isOk) {
                                File f = new File(cancion.getRutaOut());
                                if(f.exists()) {
                                    f.delete();
                                }
                                c++;
                                render(Constants.PROJECT+"/img/e.png", true);
                            }
                            else {
                                DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) files.table.getModel();
                                modelo.removeRow(0);
                                
                                render(Constants.PROJECT+"/img/f.png", true);
                            }
                            es = null;
                            ser = null;
                            if(c == PJEditCreate.songs.size()) {
                                String[] dates2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
                                dates.insertDates(dates2, Constants.PROJECT+"/img/no_cover.png", null);
                                dates.getEnabled(false);;
                                owner.panel.action.start.setEnabled(false);
                                owner.panel.action.bview.setEnabled(false);
                                visible(false, false, true);
                                c = 0;
                                tam = 0;
                                timer.stop();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            pro++;
                            if(pro >= Constants.pro.size()) {
                                pro = 0;
                            }
                            render(Constants.pro.get(pro), true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
```

Me respondo por si a alguien le puede ser de utilidad

Un saludo y gracias